# Is direct communication between a Python script and the Apache Airflow Scheduler possible?

Tags: python, airflow, airflow-scheduler

I'm learning Apache Airflow currently and want to automatically start multiple DAGs on certain events. These events are received and processed by a simple Python script.

The only way I figured out how to start a new DAG is to run the Airflow webserver next to the Airflow scheduler and call this webserver's [REST API](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/api.html#endpoints). This worked, but seems like a detour calling a web interface from the same system to call a local program on the same system. Is it possible to directly interact with the Airflow scheduler?

This is perhaps because I don't understand all concepts entirely yet, but the REST API also allows only one request at a time. So it is not possible for me to start multiple DAGs in parallel.

Comment: `calling a web interface from the same system to call a local program on the same system` - the thing is: API is created specifically to communicate with a program from the outside. It doesn't matter whether you are deployed just next to the service or on another server - API is made so that you don't have to get to or even know what is inside the service.

Comment: As for "only one request at a time" - have you checked how long it takes? Usually requests should finish in instant (by human standards). Even if the result takes long to calculate, it's a good practice to return a message instantly that basically says "hey, it will take long, the result will be at [url]" (http status code 202: "202 Accepted
The request has been accepted for processing, but the processing has not been completed. The request might or might not be eventually acted upon, and may be disallowed when processing occurs")

Comment: So there is only the REST API on purpose to guarantee proper communication with the scheduler in the backend through the specified API?
I understand requests don't take long and starting multiple DAGs in a quick sequence is in reality no issue. This is more of a question for better understanding. It is thus not possible to start multiple DAGs in parallel?

Comment: You can send multiple requests in threads. But is a few seconds that much of a difference?

Comment: If your processing takes long, just do whole processing first, and then send all requests in a loop.